# Document storage strategy for Java web apps

Tags: java, web-services, web-applications, tomcat7, cloud

We have multiple web applications for different functional areas. There is no overlap of functionality between these apps and hence they are fairly independent. All these apps generate content like PDF and XML data. Currently all these apps are storing these documents in a path relative to their web root. The documents are accessed using url relative to the app specific web root.

Now we want to move to a design where these apps store the data/files in one central location and these documents can be accessed thru a URL outside of the specific application web root. Also we want these documents to be available even if the specific application is down.

We experimented with Apache Jackrabbit etc, but most of these are CMS tools that provide a lot more than what we want. We don't need full CMC capabilities since we don't really intend to do any web publishing, editing etc. We just need a simple way for multiple apps to store files in one single location and later access them thru a URL. Some thing probably like cloud storage.

Are there any tools out there that could help us implement this? Or Design pattern?
We need

- beans from multiple apps to be able to save files in one central location (we can't use fixed disk drive location)
- common url based access to these resources

We use: Java web apps on Tomcat 7 using JSF/Myfaces

Answer (score 1):

Use an Apache web server (or other web server). Save the files in a folder published through HTTP by the server. To save them you can use any protocol that allows file transfer (FTP, SCP...).

Comment: thanks for the answer. I forgot to mention that we have access control set up using container (tomcat) and we use singlesignon enabled. Hence this needs to work from with in Tomcat environment.